# Google Cloud Function not created with Private access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating Google Cloud HTTP Function using my python script as follows:

> gcloud beta functions deploy " + function_name + " --runtime go111
>   --trigger-http --memory 128 --region " + cloud_region + " --source " + function_path + " --service-account " + my_service_account
>
> Allow unauthenticated invocations of new function
>   [ExecuteFunctionTest]? (y/N)?  N
>
> WARNING: Function created with default IAM policy. To enable
>   unauthorized access consider "gcloud alpha functions
>   add-iam-policy-binding function_name --region=us-central1
>   --member=allUsers --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"

Then when I do:

> gcloud beta functions get-iam-policy function_name

I get the following output:

```
bindings:
- members:
  - allUsers
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
etag: BwWOGyVdpDg=
version: 1
```

Why is 'allUsers' a member here?

The documentation https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating and https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access says that:

> all Cloud Functions are deployed privately, which means
>   that they can't be accessed without providing authentication
>   credentials in the request.
>
> By default, HTTP Functions are only callable by project owners,
>   editors, and Cloud Functions Admins and Developers.

But I'm able to access the Cloud Function URL using a simple curl command or Postman client without any credentials from outside the project.

What could be causing the Cloud Function to have the 'allUsers' member and be  Publicly accessible?

Comment: Side question : have you find a way to automate and say "N" to this question. I don't see commandline flags that can do that

Comment: @Thomas I did not find automated way to say N

Comment: I got the solution from the google dev mailing list : 

For boolean flags, you can use `--no-flag-name` as the opposite of `--flag-name`. In this case, you should be able to use `--no-allow-unauthenticated`. See http://cloud/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/command-conventions.
(Credit: Chris Gerber)

Comment: As per my understanding, after you deploy the Cloud Function you can invoke it without providing any token, right? Could you provide more detail of how you are invoking the Cloud Function?
The -allUsers role: roles/cloudfunctions.invoker, means that any user with the role cloudfunctions.invoker is able to invoke the CF, but it doesn’t mean that it is public without restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You can set access with the next command

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/functions/add-iam-policy-binding

and remove allUsers with the next one

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/functions/remove-iam-policy-binding

example:
gcloud alpha functions add-iam-policy-binding function_name --region=us-central1 --member=user:your.email@gmail.com --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker

gcloud alpha functions remove-iam-policy-binding function_name --region=us-central1 --member=allUsers --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker

Answer (score 0):

The new IAM features are part of the beta command set. You are using the general availability deployment (GA) commands. Delete your function, then use `gcloud beta functions deploy ...`

Comment: Hi John, I've updated the question. When I use the beta command set, I'm still getting `allUsers` member in the cloud function.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you delete the function first? Either you did not delete the function before redeploying or at one point you included the command line option `--allow-unauthenticated` which would be the case for the GA command.

Comment: It was a new function. It did not exist earlier.

Comment: @user5155835 Then I don't know. What version of `gcloud` are you using? Something is missing in your information. As a workaround just delete the allUsers IAM member.

Comment: Versions: `Google Cloud SDK 254.0.0` `beta 2019.05.17` `core 2019.07.15`

Comment: You are using the latest version. Did you use the same function name as previously or a new (never used) function name? If the same name, I am thinking that there is a bug remembering the previous deploy state.

Comment: I used a never used function name

Comment: I have no answer. The allUsers is added to the IAM Member list if the `--allow-unauthenticated` command line option is set.

Comment: Is prompt of `Allow unauthenticated invocations of new function [ExecuteFunctionTest]? (y/N)?` natural? And is my input of `N` okay?

Comment: Correct, you should select `N`. If you selected `Y`, this is the same as adding the command line option.

Comment: The state for `allUsers` is remembered across new revisions. If you selected `Y` or used the command line option, it will stay that way until you manually remove the allUsers IAM member.

Comment: I just created a complete new function which was never created before using the gcloud beta command as shown in the question. I still got allUsers as the member.

Answer (score 0):

The allUsers permission on http functions is default behavior. You can (and maybe should!) remove iam permissions with:

```
gcloud alpha functions remove-iam-policy-binding ...
```

This default behavior for HTTP functions will change after **November 1, 2019**. Currently, new HTTP functions allow unauthenticated invocation by default. New HTTP functions created after November 1, 2019 will require authentication by default. You can specify whether a function allows unauthenticated invocation at or after deployment.

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access)