# Google Cloud Functions Deploy "allow unauthenticated invocations..."

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, gcloud-python

Whenever I have to deploy a new python function using the `gcloud` sdk I get this message

> Allow unauthenticated invocations of new function  [function-name]?
>
> (y/N)?
>
> WARNING: Function created with limited-access IAM policy. To enable unauthorized access consider
>
> "gcloud alpha functions add-iam-policy-binding function-name --region=europe-west1 --member=allUsers --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"

Is there any flag I can add to the command to make it a `NO` when deploying?

This is a sample command I use to deploy one function:

```
gcloud functions deploy function-name --region=europe-west1 --entry-point function-entry-point --trigger-resource "projects/my-project/databases/(default)/documents/user_ids/{user_id}" --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create --runtime python37 --timeout 60 --project my-project
```

Comment: What happens if you specify a service account with the `--service-account` flag?

Comment: Added the full warning message that suggest using `gcloud alpha`.

There is: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--allow-unauthenticated, but the thing is that I do not want to allow unauthenticated calls.

How do you suggest to use `--service-account`

Comment: Specify a service account to gain access to the cloud function. Maybe that error is thrown if you give no information about permissions. I was reading the comments on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122047/google-cloud-function-not-created-with-private-access

Comment: That's the same question I have. But the thing is that I do not want to set any IAM policy other than not access to unauthorized access by using the `deploy` command, I already tried the `beta` and `alpha` as suggested there but still is asking me for IAM policy. I'm looking for a flag to add to the `deploy` command.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Is a python `cloud-function`

Comment: Seems like `--quiet` will ignore the question, will give me the `WARNING` but will default the function with limited IAM policy. Which is what I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud#disabling_prompts:

> You can disable prompts from gcloud CLI commands by setting the `disable_prompts` property in your configuration to `True` or by using the global `--quiet` or `-q` flag.

So for your example, you could run:

```
gcloud functions deploy function-name --quiet --region=europe-west1 --entry-point function-entry-point --trigger-resource "projects/my-project/databases/(default)/documents/user_ids/{user_id}" --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create --runtime python37 --timeout 60 --project my-project
```

Comment: I think that's just a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: This answer seems to be the officially recommended way to answer this question rather than a workaround as suggested in other comments. From the docs: "_Some gcloud CLI commands are interactive, prompting users for confirmation of an operation or requesting additional input for an entered command. In most cases, this is not desirable when running commands in a script or other automation. You can disable prompts from gcloud CLI commands [...] by using the global `--quiet` or `-q` flag_". I think the downvotes aren't justified

Answer (score 18):

I just encountered this problem as well and discovered that you can supply `--no-allow-unauthenticated` to pre-emptively answer "no" to this question.

```
gcloud functions deploy MyFunction \
  --runtime=go116 --trigger-http --no-allow-unauthenticated
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Select the service
2. Click Show Info Panel to display the Permissions tab.
3. In the Add members field, allUsers
4. Select the Cloud Functions Invoker from roles
5. Add

or

```
  gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION \
  --member='serviceAccount:FUNCTION_IDENTITY' \
  --role='roles/cloudfunctions.invoker'

 gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding [SERVICE_NAME] \
    --member="allUsers" \
    --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
```

Comment: just modified according to the resource of cloud functions